# How to copy a website inside my WWW to another computer and make it work?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, apache2, php

I have designed a website to create and sign certificates (.csr, .key, .crt, .p12) in my netbook using Ubuntu 12.04. Now I have to demonstrate that it works but my teacher wants to test it using a lab computer (wired network) and my laptop doesn't have rj45 port.

I need to copy my project, that is in `www`, to a lab computer.

I have been trying with `cp -R` to a pendrive and then from this device to the machine, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong in the way.

Also I cant find to launch index from WWW.

Comment: How was the site created?

Comment: On the server, you will also need to configure apache and install any additional services you are using (mysql, php, etc). You will likely need to configure mysql and php if you are using them.

Comment: What OS is the lab machine running?

Comment: Is it possible to use nautilus?

Answer (score 1):

The copy and paste procedure of a whole web site can works, but it depends on several things.

One of them is the environment. You must need to use the same technology. e.g. If your system use a database, you will need the same database and the same credentials to login successfully.

Also its very possible that the links of your site are pointing to different places after move the whole project to a different directory. Not only simple `a` links, but JavaScript code, CSS files and more. That behavior depends on your code.

Theoretically, if you solve this issues, you shouldn't have problems to move the project copying the files.

---

About your mention of the problem trying to make the `index` file works, are you sure that the lab computer have a completely functional LAMP environment? Is it correct the content of the `/etc/hosts` file?